# Image component won't display in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, modal-dialog, components

I'm working on a small web app where there's a "Gallery" including some random pictures. Currently, I have it set up so that when you click on one of the pictures, a modal will open. What I'm trying to do is make it so that the picture (GalleryPic) that gets clicked on opens in the modal but larger. Currently, the modal itself opens without issue, but I can't get the GalleryPic picture to display at all. All that shows is the caption and an X button.

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import  ReactDOM  from "react-dom";
import GalleryPic from "./GalleryPic";
import pictures from './imagedata'


export const Modal = ( { setShowModal }, {src, alt}) => {
    // close modal when clicking outside it
    const modalRef = useRef();
    const closeModal = (e) => {
        if (e.target === modalRef.current) {
            setShowModal(false);
        }
    };

    //render the modal JSX in the poral div (need to back and create that!!!!)
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div className="container" ref={modalRef} onClick={closeModal}>
            <div className="modal">
                <GalleryPic src={src} alt={alt}/>
                <h2>Modal is still under construction!</h2>
                <button onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>X</button>
            </div>
        </div>,
        document.getElementById("portal")
    );
};
```

Can anyone see why the GalleryPic would not display in the modal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing one object as component props

```
export const Modal = ({setShowModal, src, alt}) => {
```